# how to set scrollbar so it doesn't reset

Tags: javascript, html, scrollbar

a scrollbar that **doesn't** reset

basically I want to set the scrollbar so that stays in the position it's been moved to, including when the page has been refreshed. It would then stay there until its been moved again. is this possible? 
would appreciate any help you can offer. please keep it simple mind, Im pretty new to code!
thanks, Aaron

Comment: What kind of scrollbar? A GUI app you're doing? Java? Windows? X-Windows? A browser? A bar in the Skyrim game?

Comment: *[...] including when the page has been refreshed [...]* -- I'd say he's talking about a web-page.

Comment: sorry yeah, in a webpage. working within safari and firefox mainly. the ultimate goal is to have a scrollbar which is permanently retained until moved again. retained beyond refreshing the page, even after the browser has been quit. any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This is well described in this blog post:

- [Retain scroll position after browser refresh](http://worthposting.wordpress.com/2008/07/10/retain-scroll-position-after-browser-refresh/)

You basically need to fetch the current scroll-position in JavaScript, send it along the new request. You then "bounce back" the scroll-position to the client in the response. The JavaScript on the client then restores the scroll-position.

Comment: this is great but I wanted to go beyond refreshing to even staying the same when a browser is quit entirely. is that just not doable?

Comment: I think it's doable. You could try posting the last known scroll-position to the server on some onunload event. You could also, continuously, put the last scroll-pos in [local storage](http://php-html.net/tutorials/html5-local-storage-guide/). Both safari and firefox supports this.

Comment: crikey ill have a go combining codes, might have a few difficulties if anyone can spell it out

Comment: can't seem to work it out, think Im in way over my head. can anyone dumb it down for me?

Comment: found this which supposedly remembers text http://jsbin.com/iqura/2/edit#javascript,html